# Variance of stochastic variable with X and Y

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation, covariance, variance

if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent stochastic variables where $Var(x) = 1.95$, $Var(Y)=0.9$ and $Cov(X,Y)=0.8$. Find the variance of $Z = -4X+4Y-6$

I tried using $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2cov(X,Y)$ where I basically tried to say
$Var(-4X+4Y-6) = Var(-4X) + Var(4Y) + Var(-6) + 2Cov(-4X, 4Y)...$ but this seems like an incorrect approach and doesn't yield me the correct answer (given that my calculations are correct).

I cant find any other logical formulas in my book, only the definitions for variance and covariance.. The formula I tried I found on wolfram.

Comment: Hint: Adding constants doesn't affect the variance.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that you also square the coefficient that you factor out from covariance... Thanks for the hint anyways

Comment: The techniques here are similar to what was covered by your [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916867/covariance-for-stochastic-variables).  Did that resolve your concerns about this calculation?